Non-word characters in SHAP's default tokenizer
My basic question is:  why are the non-word characters making it into my SHAP output, and how do I prevent it?
I am applying SHAP to a black-box machine learning model fn_predict_proba() (the model has been trained to return an estimated probability that a given text string belongs to a certain conceptual category) by following the demo code at
link.   When I have completed computing a set of SHAP values to explain the importance of the words in the string
text_example = 'AreWe In A Boat --- bChiLders ---- Husband, father, Navy doctor. Royals/Chiefs/Mizzou. Life isnt about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself'

then the values tabulate out beginning as follows:




shap_values
data_values




0
AreWe
0.1088


1
In
0.184


2
A
0.0791


3
Boat
0.0663


4
-
0.0462


5
-
0.036


6
-
0.04


7

0.1146


8
bChiLders
0.0471


9
-
-0.0004


10
-
-0.0414


11
-
-0.0034


12
-
0.0075


13

-0.0271


14
Husband,
-0.0452


15

0.0091


16
father,
-0.0351


17

-0.0509


18
Navy
-0.0626


19
doctor.
-0.0172


20

0.0685


21
Royals/
0.075


22
Chiefs/
-0.0079



I am surprised to see that the words in the tokenization include things like '', '-', father,, Royals/, etc., that include non-word characters.  (Or no characters, in the case of that empty string.)
The tokenization itself comes from this code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import transformers
import shap

def custom_tokenizer(s, return_offsets_mapping=True):
    """Custom tokenizers conform to a subset of the transformers API."""
    pos = 0
    offset_ranges = []
    input_ids = []
    for m in re.finditer(r"\W", s):
        start, end = m.span(0)
        offset_ranges.append((pos, start))
        input_ids.append(s[pos:start])
        pos = end
    if pos != len(s):
        offset_ranges.append((pos, len(s)))
        input_ids.append(s[pos:])
    out = {}
    out["input_ids"] = input_ids
    if return_offsets_mapping:
        out["offset_mapping"] = offset_ranges
    return out

masker = shap.maskers.Text(custom_tokenizer)
explainer = shap.Explainer(fn_predict_proba, masker, output_names=class_names)

and if I apply it directly, via custom_tokenizer(text_example), the result is
['AreWe', 'In', 'A', 'Boat', '', '', '', '', 'bChiLders', '', '', '', '', '', 'Husband', '', 'father', '', 'Navy', 'doctor', '', 'Royals', 'Chiefs', 'Mizzou', '', 'Life', 'isnt', 'about', 'finding', 'yourself', '', 'Life', 'is', 'about', 'creating', 'yourself'].
So, applying the tokenizer directly gives a pretty good result with no non-word characters.  (Although I'd like the empty strings to be gone.)  But then when I call explainer(text_example ), it comes out differently -- in the numerical SHAP weights in the table above, the tokens include non-word characters, repeated tokens, and empty tokens.
Can you help me understand and remediate?
